# aj query use fails to fill with last known value

Tags: kdb

I’m doing a project on some price data and I’m looking to use aj to fill in days when I’m missing an average price with the price when last traded.

I use the same table twice in aj to try and fill the blanks. However, it doesn’t fill as I would have thought it would.

Could you advise where I’m going wrong in the simplified example below?

Simon

```
tt:([]t:1998.01.02 1998.01.03 1998.01.04 1998.01.05 1998.01.06 1998.01.07 1998.01.09;

    r:`COSC.SI`COSC.SI`COSC.SI`COSC.SI`COSC.SI`COSC.SI`COSC.SI;

    p:(0.9;0n;0n;0n;0.8;0.7473684;0.7195));

qt:([]t:1998.01.02 1998.01.03 1998.01.04 1998.01.05 1998.01.06 1998.01.07 1998.01.09;

    r:`COSC.SI`COSC.SI`COSC.SI`COSC.SI`COSC.SI`COSC.SI`COSC.SI;

    q:(0.9;0n;0n;0n;0.8;0.7473684;0.7195));

aj[`r`t;tt;qt]
```

got:

```
t          r       p         q       

--------------------------------------

1998.01.02 COSC.SI 0.9       0.9     

1998.01.03 COSC.SI                   

1998.01.04 COSC.SI                   

1998.01.05 COSC.SI                   

1998.01.06 COSC.SI 0.8       0.8     

1998.01.07 COSC.SI 0.7473684 0.7473684

1998.01.09 COSC.SI 0.7195    0.7195
```

expected:

```
t          r       p         q       

--------------------------------------

1998.01.02 COSC.SI 0.9       0.9     

1998.01.03 COSC.SI 0.9       0.9

1998.01.04 COSC.SI 0.9       0.9 

1998.01.05 COSC.SI 0.9       0.9 

1998.01.06 COSC.SI 0.8       0.8     

1998.01.07 COSC.SI 0.7473684 0.7473684

1998.01.09 COSC.SI 0.7195    0.7195
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`fills`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/fill/) operator to replace nulls with most recent values. Statement

```
fills tt
```

will fill all columns. To specify columns explicitly use:

```
update fills p from tt
```

---

Separately. `aj` doesn't work in way you expect, because nulls are not removed from `qt` table. Hence, null q values are joined to null p values. If you filter nulls, you'll get result you expect:

```
aj[`r`t;tt;delete from qt where null q]
```

But this is not the best way of filling gaps with most recent values

Comment: thanks so much - explanation and alternate suggestion. I shall use fills as you suggest.